# Syntax for URL to pass query parameters from one rdl to another

Tags: powerbi-paginated-reports

I have 2 paginated reports that run fine independently. Now they need to be linked such that a textbox field (an expression) value needs to link to the second report and the parameters need to be passed in the url to the 2nd report. I don't get an error msg, but the field isn't 'clickable'.  Here is the url: ="javascript:void(window.open('https://Myserver/MyRptName&DimQVRCode=" & Lookup(Fields!QVR_Code.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, Fields!QVR_Code.Value, "QVR Dataset") & "&FromDate=" & Parameters!FromDate.Value & "&ToDate=" & Parameters!ToDate.Value & "','_blank'))".  If I just hard code values in the url (to test) it all works. I've received a lot of help on this but it hasn't worked yet. I'm sure it's something I am doing wrong. Does anyone have any guidance on the syntax?

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE!!
Figured it out!..the correct syntax is to put a ? after the MyRptName, and before each paramter name to put rp: and that fixed it.  I read a lot of posts on this, and in the end this is what worked...